# How to animate an ImageView to move to a random value and have the value randomize on each repeat in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

I'm trying to create a vibrating animation for an image view in Kotlin.

Here's the code I'm starting with:

```
var randomX = Random.nextInt(-100, 100).toFloat()
var moveX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.TRANSLATION_X, randomX).apply {
  duration = 100
  repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE

  addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
      randomX = Random.nextInt(-100, 100).toFloat()
    }
  })
}

var randomY = Random.nextInt(-100, 100).toFloat()
var moveY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, randomY).apply {
  duration = 100
  repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE

  addListener(object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator?) {}
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator?) {
      randomY = Random.nextInt(-100, 100).toFloat()
    }
  })
}

var move = AnimatorSet()
move.playTogether(moveX, moveY)
move.start()
```

What I'm having trouble with is changing the random values and then updating the animation with the new random values on each repeat. It always just uses the initial values.

Answer (score 0):

Your listeners are just changing those `var`s when the animation repeats, the animations are already defined with the original values, so nothing changes when it loops - it just does the same thing again.

You can get the effect you want by basically defining a new animation each time - here's a way with the [`ViewPropertyAnimator`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#view-prop-animator) approach:

```
fun randomPosition() = Random.nextInt(-100, 100).toFloat()
fun vibrate() {
    imageView.animate()
        .translationX(randomPosition())
        .translationY(randomPosition())
        .setDuration(100)
        .withEndAction(::vibrate)
        .start()
}
```

it's basically doing the thing, then it has an "end action" which just calls the function again. Because it creates a new animation each time, it grabs a new pair of random values.

You could also control the number of repeats if you wanted!

```
fun vibrate(count: Int = 10) {
    if (count < 1) return
    imageView.animate()
        .translationX(randomPosition())
        .translationY(randomPosition())
        .setDuration(100)
        .withEndAction{ vibrate(count-1) }
        .start()
}
```

It's just decrementing the number of vibrations left, until you hit zero and it stops animating. I used a default parameter value so you can define the standard number of vibes there, and just call `vibrate()` from anywhere that uses it.

(Also it's not recursive because it's not actually calling the function from within itself - it's doing it at a later point from inside a function object handed to the animator. In case you were worried about that!)